# java.lang.LinkageError: ClassCastException attempting to castjar

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, confluent-schema-registry, jakarta-migration

I am trying to build a kafka consumer app with Spring Boot v3.1.5 and Java 17. It attempts to read from a kafka topic via a schema registry. The exception is thrown when an avro is attempted to be read.

The issue seems to be around **Jakarta** classes and their version compatibility. Need help to successfully read topic messages.

My pom.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example.kafkaconsumerdemo</groupId>
    <artifactId>avro-processor</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>kafka-consumer-demo</name>
    <description>Kafka consumer demo</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
<!--        <avro.version>1.11.3</avro.version>-->
        <avro.version>1.11.2</avro.version>
        <kafka-avro-serializer.version>6.2.0</kafka-avro-serializer.version>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>confluent</id>
            <name>Confluent</name>
            <url>https://packages.confluent.io/maven/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>     
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams</artifactId>
        </dependency>    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
            <version>${avro.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-avro-serializer</artifactId>
            <version>${kafka-avro-serializer.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${avro.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>${avro.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro-ipc</artifactId>
            <version>${avro.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-testcontainers</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>9.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.6</version>
<!--            <version>3.1.0</version>-->
        </dependency>

        <!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>2.2.12</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

<!--        &lt;!&ndash; https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-web-api &ndash;&gt;-->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>javax</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>8.0.1</version>-->
<!--            <scope>provided</scope>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>2.24</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->


    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
                <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${avro.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>schemas</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>schema</goal>
                            <goal>protocol</goal>
                            <goal>idl-protocol</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/avro/</sourceDirectory>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Currently, seeing the below exception stack trace:

> 2023-11-20T14:54:27.919Z  INFO 674 --- [pool-2-thread-1]
> o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 3.4.1
> 2023-11-20T14:54:27.919Z  INFO 674 --- [pool-2-thread-1]
> o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId:
> 8a516edc2755df89 2023-11-20T14:54:27.919Z  INFO 674 ---
> [pool-2-thread-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka
> startTimeMs: 1700492067919 2023-11-20T14:54:27.925Z  INFO 674 ---
> [pool-2-thread-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Consumer
> clientId=consumer-anonymous.0fa8a41c-49f8-4cdb-bb46-b87da258dee6-4,
> groupId=anonymous.0fa8a41c-49f8-4cdb-bb46-b87da258dee6] Cluster ID:
> ivKDU44TT6ae4LI9HsI_8g 2023-11-20T14:54:27.929Z  INFO 674 ---
> [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer
> clientId=consumer-anonymous.0fa8a41c-49f8-4cdb-bb46-b87da258dee6-2,
> groupId=anonymous.0fa8a41c-49f8-4cdb-bb46-b87da258dee6] Successfully
> joined group with generation Generation{generationId=1,
> memberId='consumer-anonymous.0fa8a41c-49f8-4cdb-bb46-b87da258dee6-2-543b2ae3-aaea-4006-bbe1-608455db755e',
> protocol='range'} 2023-11-20T14:54:27.931Z  INFO 674 ---
> [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer
> clientId=consumer-anonymous.0fa8a41c-49f8-4cdb-bb46-b87da258dee6-2,
> groupId=anonymous.0fa8a41c-49f8-4cdb-bb46-b87da258dee6] Finished
> assignment for group at generation 1:
> {consumer-anonymous.0fa8a41c-49f8-4cdb-bb46-b87da258dee6-2-543b2ae3-aaea-4006-bbe1-608455db755e=Assignment(partitions=[employees-topic-0])}
> 2023-11-20T14:54:27.936Z  INFO 674 --- [container-0-C-1]
> o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer
> clientId=consumer-anonymous.0fa8a41c-49f8-4cdb-bb46-b87da258dee6-2,
> groupId=anonymous.0fa8a41c-49f8-4cdb-bb46-b87da258dee6] Successfully
> synced group in generation Generation{generationId=1,
> memberId='consumer-anonymous.0fa8a41c-49f8-4cdb-bb46-b87da258dee6-2-543b2ae3-aaea-4006-bbe1-608455db755e',
> protocol='range'} 2023-11-20T14:54:27.936Z  INFO 674 ---
> [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer
> clientId=consumer-anonymous.0fa8a41c-49f8-4cdb-bb46-b87da258dee6-2,
> groupId=anonymous.0fa8a41c-49f8-4cdb-bb46-b87da258dee6] Notifying
> assignor about the new Assignment(partitions=[employees-topic-0])
> 2023-11-20T14:54:27.937Z  INFO 674 --- [pool-2-thread-1]
> o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer
> clientId=consumer-anonymous.0fa8a41c-49f8-4cdb-bb46-b87da258dee6-4,
> groupId=anonymous.0fa8a41c-49f8-4cdb-bb46-b87da258dee6] Discovered
> group coordinator 127.0.0.1:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
> 2023-11-20T14:54:27.938Z  INFO 674 --- [container-0-C-1]
> o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer
> clientId=consumer-anonymous.0fa8a41c-49f8-4cdb-bb46-b87da258dee6-2,
> groupId=anonymous.0fa8a41c-49f8-4cdb-bb46-b87da258dee6] Adding newly
> assigned partitions: employees-topic-0 2023-11-20T14:54:27.940Z  INFO
> 674 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  :
> [Consumer
> clientId=consumer-anonymous.0fa8a41c-49f8-4cdb-bb46-b87da258dee6-2,
> groupId=anonymous.0fa8a41c-49f8-4cdb-bb46-b87da258dee6] Found no
> committed offset for partition employees-topic-0
> 2023-11-20T14:54:27.940Z  INFO 674 --- [pool-2-thread-1]
> o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer
> clientId=consumer-anonymous.0fa8a41c-49f8-4cdb-bb46-b87da258dee6-4,
> groupId=anonymous.0fa8a41c-49f8-4cdb-bb46-b87da258dee6] Found no
> committed offset for partition employees-topic-0
> 2023-11-20T14:54:27.942Z  INFO 674 --- [container-0-C-1]
> o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer
> clientId=consumer-anonymous.0fa8a41c-49f8-4cdb-bb46-b87da258dee6-2,
> groupId=anonymous.0fa8a41c-49f8-4cdb-bb46-b87da258dee6] Found no
> committed offset for partition employees-topic-0
> 2023-11-20T14:54:27.945Z  INFO 674 --- [container-0-C-1]
> o.a.k.c.c.internals.SubscriptionState    : [Consumer
> clientId=consumer-anonymous.0fa8a41c-49f8-4cdb-bb46-b87da258dee6-2,
> groupId=anonymous.0fa8a41c-49f8-4cdb-bb46-b87da258dee6] Resetting
> offset for partition employees-topic-0 to position
> FetchPosition{offset=16, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty,
> currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[127.0.0.1:9092 (id: 0
> rack: null)], epoch=0}}. 2023-11-20T14:54:27.949Z  INFO 674 ---
> [container-0-C-1] o.s.c.s.b.k.KafkaMessageChannelBinder$2  :
> anonymous.0fa8a41c-49f8-4cdb-bb46-b87da258dee6: partitions assigned:
> [employees-topic-0] 2023-11-20T14:54:32.971Z ERROR 674 ---
> [container-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Stopping
> container due to an Error
>
> java.lang.LinkageError: ClassCastException: attempting to
> castjar:file:/Users/saurav.das2/.m2/repository/jakarta/ws/rs/jakarta.ws.rs-api/2.1.6/jakarta.ws.rs-api-2.1.6.jar!/javax/ws/rs/ext/RuntimeDelegate.class to
> jar:file:/Users/saurav.das2/.m2/repository/jakarta/ws/rs/jakarta.ws.rs-api/2.1.6/jakarta.ws.rs-api-2.1.6.jar!/javax/ws/rs/ext/RuntimeDelegate.class   at
> javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate(RuntimeDelegate.java:124)
> ~[jakarta.ws.rs-api-2.1.6.jar:2.1.6]  at
> javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.getInstance(RuntimeDelegate.java:96)
> ~[jakarta.ws.rs-api-2.1.6.jar:2.1.6]  at
> javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.newInstance(UriBuilder.java:72)
> ~[jakarta.ws.rs-api-2.1.6.jar:2.1.6]  at
> javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromPath(UriBuilder.java:125)
> ~[jakarta.ws.rs-api-2.1.6.jar:2.1.6]  at
> io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getId(RestService.java:713)
> ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-6.2.0.jar:na]  at
> io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getId(RestService.java:699)
> ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-6.2.0.jar:na]  at
> io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaByIdFromRegistry(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:224)
> ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-6.2.0.jar:na]  at
> io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaBySubjectAndId(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:298)
> ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-6.2.0.jar:na]  at
> io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaById(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:283)
> ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-6.2.0.jar:na]  at
> io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer$DeserializationContext.schemaFromRegistry(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:307)
> ~[kafka-avro-serializer-6.2.0.jar:na]     at
> io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:107)
> ~[kafka-avro-serializer-6.2.0.jar:na]     at
> io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:86)
> ~[kafka-avro-serializer-6.2.0.jar:na]     at
> io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(KafkaAvroDeserializer.java:55)
> ~[kafka-avro-serializer-6.2.0.jar:na]     at
> org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer.deserialize(Deserializer.java:60)
> ~[kafka-clients-3.4.1.jar:na]     at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseRecord(Fetcher.java:1429)
> ~[kafka-clients-3.4.1.jar:na]     at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.access$3400(Fetcher.java:133)
> ~[kafka-clients-3.4.1.jar:na]     at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$CompletedFetch.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:1661)
> ~[kafka-clients-3.4.1.jar:na]     at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$CompletedFetch.access$1900(Fetcher.java:1497)
> ~[kafka-clients-3.4.1.jar:na]     at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:717)
> ~[kafka-clients-3.4.1.jar:na]     at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.collectFetch(Fetcher.java:683)
> ~[kafka-clients-3.4.1.jar:na]     at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1314)
> ~[kafka-clients-3.4.1.jar:na]     at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1243)
> ~[kafka-clients-3.4.1.jar:na]     at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1216)
> ~[kafka-clients-3.4.1.jar:na]     at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
> at
> org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
> ~[spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]   at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:237)
> ~[spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]   at
> jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy109.poll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]     at
> org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollConsumer(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1676)
> ~[spring-kafka-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]     at
> org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doPoll(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1651)
> ~[spring-kafka-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]     at
> org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1452)
> ~[spring-kafka-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]     at
> org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1344)
> ~[spring-kafka-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]     at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1804)
> ~[na:na]  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]
>
> 2023-11-20T14:54:32.975Z  INFO 674 --- [container-0-C-1]
> o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer
> clientId=consumer-anonymous.0fa8a41c-49f8-4cdb-bb46-b87da258dee6-2,
> groupId=anonymous.0fa8a41c-49f8-4cdb-bb46-b87da258dee6] Revoke
> previously assigned partitions employees-topic-0
> 2023-11-20T14:54:32.975Z  INFO 674 --- [container-0-C-1]
> o.s.c.s.b.k.KafkaMessageChannelBinder$2  :
> anonymous.0fa8a41c-49f8-4cdb-bb46-b87da258dee6: partitions revoked:
> [employees-topic-0] 2023-11-20T14:54:32.975Z  INFO 674 ---
> [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer
> clientId=consumer-anonymous.0fa8a41c-49f8-4cdb-bb46-b87da258dee6-2,
> groupId=anonymous.0fa8a41c-49f8-4cdb-bb46-b87da258dee6] Member
> consumer-anonymous.0fa8a41c-49f8-4cdb-bb46-b87da258dee6-2-543b2ae3-aaea-4006-bbe1-608455db755e
> sending LeaveGroup request to coordinator 127.0.0.1:9092 (id:
> 2147483647 rack: null) due to the consumer is being closed
> 2023-11-20T14:54:32.975Z  INFO 674 --- [container-0-C-1]
> o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer
> clientId=consumer-anonymous.0fa8a41c-49f8-4cdb-bb46-b87da258dee6-2,
> groupId=anonymous.0fa8a41c-49f8-4cdb-bb46-b87da258dee6] Resetting
> generation and member id due to: consumer pro-actively leaving the
> group 2023-11-20T14:54:32.975Z  INFO 674 --- [container-0-C-1]
> o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer
> clientId=consumer-anonymous.0fa8a41c-49f8-4cdb-bb46-b87da258dee6-2,
> groupId=anonymous.0fa8a41c-49f8-4cdb-bb46-b87da258dee6] Request
> joining group due to: consumer pro-actively leaving the group
> 2023-11-20T14:54:32.978Z  INFO 674 --- [container-0-C-1]
> o.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics    : Metrics scheduler closed
> 2023-11-20T14:54:32.978Z  INFO 674 --- [container-0-C-1]
> o.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics    : Closing reporter
> org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter 2023-11-20T14:54:32.978Z
> INFO 674 --- [container-0-C-1] o.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics
> : Metrics reporters closed 2023-11-20T14:54:32.979Z  INFO 674 ---
> [container-0-C-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : App info
> kafka.consumer for
> consumer-anonymous.0fa8a41c-49f8-4cdb-bb46-b87da258dee6-2 unregistered
> 2023-11-20T14:54:32.979Z  INFO 674 --- [container-0-C-1]
> o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    :
> anonymous.0fa8a41c-49f8-4cdb-bb46-b87da258dee6: Consumer stopped
> 2023-11-20T14:54:32.980Z ERROR 674 --- [container-0-C-1]
> o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Error while stopping the
> container
>
> java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.LinkageError:
> ClassCastException: attempting to
> castjar:file:/Users/saurav.das2/.m2/repository/jakarta/ws/rs/jakarta.ws.rs-api/2.1.6/jakarta.ws.rs-api-2.1.6.jar!/javax/ws/rs/ext/RuntimeDelegate.class to
> jar:file:/Users/saurav.das2/.m2/repository/jakarta/ws/rs/jakarta.ws.rs-api/2.1.6/jakarta.ws.rs-api-2.1.6.jar!/javax/ws/rs/ext/RuntimeDelegate.class   at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:315)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:320)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1807)
> ~[na:na]  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]
> Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: ClassCastException: attempting to
> castjar:file:/Users/saurav.das2/.m2/repository/jakarta/ws/rs/jakarta.ws.rs-api/2.1.6/jakarta.ws.rs-api-2.1.6.jar!/javax/ws/rs/ext/RuntimeDelegate.class to
> jar:file:/Users/saurav.das2/.m2/repository/jakarta/ws/rs/jakarta.ws.rs-api/2.1.6/jakarta.ws.rs-api-2.1.6.jar!/javax/ws/rs/ext/RuntimeDelegate.class   at
> javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate(RuntimeDelegate.java:124)
> ~[jakarta.ws.rs-api-2.1.6.jar:2.1.6]  at
> javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.getInstance(RuntimeDelegate.java:96)
> ~[jakarta.ws.rs-api-2.1.6.jar:2.1.6]  at
> javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.newInstance(UriBuilder.java:72)
> ~[jakarta.ws.rs-api-2.1.6.jar:2.1.6]  at
> javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromPath(UriBuilder.java:125)
> ~[jakarta.ws.rs-api-2.1.6.jar:2.1.6]  at
> io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getId(RestService.java:713)
> ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-6.2.0.jar:na]  at
> io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getId(RestService.java:699)
> ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-6.2.0.jar:na]  at
> io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaByIdFromRegistry(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:224)
> ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-6.2.0.jar:na]  at
> io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaBySubjectAndId(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:298)
> ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-6.2.0.jar:na]  at
> io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaById(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:283)
> ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-6.2.0.jar:na]  at
> io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer$DeserializationContext.schemaFromRegistry(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:307)
> ~[kafka-avro-serializer-6.2.0.jar:na]     at
> io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:107)
> ~[kafka-avro-serializer-6.2.0.jar:na]     at
> io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:86)
> ~[kafka-avro-serializer-6.2.0.jar:na]     at
> io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(KafkaAvroDeserializer.java:55)
> ~[kafka-avro-serializer-6.2.0.jar:na]     at
> org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer.deserialize(Deserializer.java:60)
> ~[kafka-clients-3.4.1.jar:na]     at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseRecord(Fetcher.java:1429)
> ~[kafka-clients-3.4.1.jar:na]     at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.access$3400(Fetcher.java:133)
> ~[kafka-clients-3.4.1.jar:na]     at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$CompletedFetch.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:1661)
> ~[kafka-clients-3.4.1.jar:na]     at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$CompletedFetch.access$1900(Fetcher.java:1497)
> ~[kafka-clients-3.4.1.jar:na]     at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:717)
> ~[kafka-clients-3.4.1.jar:na]     at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.collectFetch(Fetcher.java:683)
> ~[kafka-clients-3.4.1.jar:na]     at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1314)
> ~[kafka-clients-3.4.1.jar:na]     at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1243)
> ~[kafka-clients-3.4.1.jar:na]     at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1216)
> ~[kafka-clients-3.4.1.jar:na]     at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
> at
> org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
> ~[spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]   at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:237)
> ~[spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]   at
> jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy109.poll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]     at
> org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollConsumer(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1676)
> ~[spring-kafka-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]     at
> org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doPoll(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1651)
> ~[spring-kafka-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]     at
> org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1452)
> ~[spring-kafka-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]     at
> org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1344)
> ~[spring-kafka-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]     at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1804)
> ~[na:na]  ... 1 common frames omitted
>
> 2023-11-20T14:55:54.007Z  INFO 674 --- [ionShutdownHook]
> s.i.k.i.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter : stopped
> org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter@3636f2a7
> 2023-11-20T14:55:54.013Z  INFO 674 --- [ionShutdownHook]
> o.s.c.stream.binder.BinderErrorChannel   : Channel
> 'application.kafka-1811235424.argosPaymentsConsumer-in-0.errors' has 1
> subscriber(s). 2023-11-20T14:55:54.024Z  INFO 674 ---
> [ionShutdownHook] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Removing
> {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger}
> as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel 2023-11-20T14:55:54.024Z
> INFO 674 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel
> : Channel 'application.errorChannel' has 0 subscriber(s).
> 2023-11-20T14:55:54.025Z  INFO 674 --- [ionShutdownHook]
> o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : stopped bean
> '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger'
> 2023-11-20T14:55:54.028Z  INFO 674 --- [| adminclient-2]
> o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : App info kafka.admin.client
> for adminclient-2 unregistered 2023-11-20T14:55:54.029Z  INFO 674 ---
> [| adminclient-2] o.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics    : Metrics
> scheduler closed 2023-11-20T14:55:54.029Z  INFO 674 --- [|

Comment: I am not familiar with this particular scenario, but failure to cast a class to itself usually means that the from and to classes were loaded by different class loaders somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You depend on old `javax` dependency like `jakarta.ws.rs-api` in 2.1.6 version. It's `jakarta` dependency since 3.0.0 and will be mandatory in order to migrate to Spring Boot 3.

Also see : https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/issues/2770

Seems that migration to SB3 will be complicated due to this issue.

Hope you'll find a solution which is not going back to Spring Boot 2.7